# Is there a PHP function for swapping the values of two variables?

Tags: php, function, swap

Say for instance I have ...

```php
$var1 = "ABC"
$var2 = 123
```

and under certain conditions I want to swap the two around like so...

```php
$var1 = 123
$var2 = "ABC"
```

Is there a PHP function for doing this rather than having to create a 3rd variable to hold one of the values then redefining each, like so...

```php
$var3 = $var1
$var1 = $var2
$var2 = $var3
```

For such a simple task its probably quicker using a 3rd variable anyway and I could always create my own function if I really wanted to. Just wondered if something like that exists?

Update: Using a 3rd variable or wrapping it in a function is the best solution. It's clean and simple. I asked the question more out of curiosity and the answer chosen was kind of 'the next best alternative'. Just use a 3rd variable.

Comment: You can use xor too, like... `b = a xor b`, `a = a xor b`, `b = a xor b` should do the trick... Dunno if theres a function, I'm not good with PHP.

Comment: These answers resemble some sort of an obfuscation contest.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There isn't a built-in function. Use `swap3()` as mentioned below.

#### Summary

As many mentioned, there are multiple ways to do this, most noticable are these 4 methods:

```
function swap1(&$x, &$y) {
    // Warning: works correctly with numbers ONLY!
    $x ^= $y ^= $x ^= $y;
}
function swap2(&$x, &$y) {
    list($x,$y) = array($y, $x);
}
function swap3(&$x, &$y) {
    $tmp=$x;
    $x=$y;
    $y=$tmp;
}
function swap4(&$x, &$y) {
    extract(array('x' => $y, 'y' => $x));
}
```

I tested the 4 methods under a for-loop of 1000 iterations, to find the fastest of them:

- `swap1()` = scored approximate average of **0.19** seconds.
- `swap2()` = scored approximate average of **0.42** seconds.
- `swap3()` = scored approximate average of **0.16** seconds. ***Winner!***
- `swap4()` = scored approximate average of **0.73** seconds.

And for readability, I find `swap3()` is better than the other functions.

#### Note

- `swap2()` and `swap4()` are always slower than the other ones because of the function call.
- `swap1()` and `swap3()` both performance speed are very similar, but most of the time `swap3()` is slightly faster.
- **Warning:** `swap1()` works only with numbers!

Comment: Changed the answer to this one since the question seems to get a lot of attention and you've bench marked them. swap3 is basically the same as the original question wrapped up in function. Proof that simplicity is often better, even if it means extra lines!

Comment: Yep, I upvote your summary too. But you can remove `swap1`, it does some real bulshit.

Comment: Swap2 is clearly best for readability/writability. Swap1 is just presumptuous and Swap3 is the 'non swapping' way to do it. Obviously any option is okay if you make your own wrapper function that works how you want, as `swap(&$a,&$b)` can be useful.

Comment: Swap1 was perfect for me as all I wanted was to swap bytes if one was bigger than the other

Comment: @StevenByrne Note that swap1 only works with numbers!

Comment: Yes, which was perfect for my use (number of bits (ints) needing to be swapped)

Comment: Why not remove swap1 if it works only with numbers? It's such a big caveat and this function has no advantage over just swapping as in swap3

Comment: There is another one way
extract(array('a'=>$b,'b'=>$a));
Please add benchmark for it.

Comment: @AlexeyMuravyov Thank you. Included it.

Comment: for what it's worth `swap2()` can now be rewritten per [@Pawel Dubiel's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39692850/1767412) and is ***much*** faster than it was when those benchmarks were written.  I ran some benchmarks of my own and over 1 million iterations it only took 0.01 seconds longer than `swap3()` which is of course negligible.  Also, `[$a, $b] = [$b, $a];` looks great.

Comment: Warning: `swap1` does not work if `$x` and `$y` are the same variable.

Answer (score 103):

There's no function I know of, but there is a one-liner courtesy of [Pete Graham](http://tech.petegraham.co.uk/2007/03/29/php-swap-variables-one-liner/):

```
list($a,$b) = array($b,$a);
```

not sure whether I like this from a maintenance perspective, though, as it's not really intuitive to understand.

Also, as @Paul Dixon points out, it is not very efficient, and is costlier than using a temporary variable. Possibly of note in a very big loop.

However, a situation where this is necessary smells a bit wrong to me, anyway. If you want to discuss it: What do you need this for?

Comment: +1 - found the same, and agree, not sure I like it either - using a temp variable is considerably better - as is writing your own swap method if you find yourself doing this often.

Comment: +1, Beat me to it as well :) I like the idea in principle, but unfortunately the PHP syntax just leaves a bad taste...

Comment: wow, super quick response. I take my hat off to all of you!
is a nice little trick that.

Comment: @Taylor there is also a question to you in this quick response.

Comment: using it to switch 2 values in a field if some plonker puts values in the form around the wrong way. The values are fairly restricted to what they can be so its easy enough to figure out whether they should have been around the other way. More of a usability thing so it helps out those that aren't great on a computer... or just having a bad moment. :-)

Comment: as this is the accepted answer for a question that might educate others, it's worth pointing out just how inefficient this is. You're asking PHP to create an array, only to immediately discard it. I benchmarked this approach against using a temporary variable, and found that using a temp variable is over 7 times faster. I would also argue it makes the intent clearer too, as it's a common idiom!

Comment: @Paul great information about the benchmark - it's meaningless for one or two operations, but will make a difference in loops. Editing the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @paul figured as much, simplicity usually is. Good to see an actual benchmark.

Comment: And since this answerer is sceptical, what made me Google whether PHP had a built-in `swap()` is iterating through an array where the keys hold value - e.g. they indicate columns in a database, and the values indicate values. However if there isn't a pair, just a value, then you can have the option to use the value as the key (swap) and use a default value. Since in my example I don't need to keep the key, it's not _really_ essential, but if I did need to keep the array index, I'd rather use a (bult-in) `swap()` call than creating a stupidly named temporary. But, this isn't built-in...

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *404 File not found*.

Comment: It's also worth noted that you can swap more than 2 variables with this code snippet: `$x = 'x'; $y = 'y'; $z = 'z'; list($x, $y, $z) = [$y, $z, $x];` will return `$x = 'y'; $y = 'z'; $z = 'x';`. Useful for stack ordering, if you don't already have an array for this :-)

Answer (score 77):

Yes, there now exists something like that. It's not a function but a language construct (available since PHP 7.1). It allows this short syntax:

```
 [$a, $b] = [$b, $a];
```

See ["Square bracket syntax for array destructuring assignment"](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax) for more details.

Comment: My vote is for this one because:  It is easily done _inline_, and it is only _one line_  (I did not test to see if it runs faster than the function call options.)  My programming time is usually more valuable than the computer time.

Comment: My vote for this too

Comment: This is essentially the same as swap2() in the accepted answer, ie list($x, $y) = array($y, $x);

Comment: @oomp I agree but language construct wins over functions call.

Comment: @AhsaanYousuf https://www.php.net/list "Like array(), this is not really a function, but a language construct. "

Answer (score 17):

It is also possible to use the old XOR trick  ( However it works only correctly for integers, and it doesn't make code easier to read..  )

```
$a ^= $b ^= $a ^= $b;
```

Comment: If you use it with words, containing same parts, it returns funny and unexpected result: http://ideone.com/NGQVYH

Answer (score 10):

Yes, try [this](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/swap-two-variables.htm):

```
// Test variables
$a = "content a";
$b = "content b";

// Swap $a and $b
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
```

This reminds me of python, where syntax like this is perfectly valid:

```
a, b = b, a
```

It's a shame you can't just do the above in PHP...

Comment: you can, as above. `[$a, $b] = [$b, $a]`

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
$a = $b + $a - ($b = $a);
```

Answer (score 7):

For numbers:

```
$a = $a+$b;
$b = $a-$b;
$a = $a-$b;
```

Working:

Let $a = 10, $b = 20.

$a = $a+$b (now, $a = 30, $b = 20)

$b = $a-$b (now, $a = 30, $b = 10)

$a = $a-$b (now, $a = 20, $b = 10 SWAPPED!)

Comment: This works only for numbers and is not a build-in PHP-function. The OP asked for a more general approach and for a predefined function.

Comment: You are right, missed it looking at all the other answers and implementations.

Comment: Though the answer is not correct specifically for the question asked, I'm glad that somebody mentioned this approach, so upvote from me :)

Comment: If your numbers are too big, this method could overflow.

Answer (score 5):

```
list($var1,$var2) = array($var2,$var1);
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is faster and needs lesser memory.

```
function swap(&$a, &$b) {
    $a = $a ^ $b;
    $b = $a ^ $b;
    $a = $a ^ $b;
}

$a = "One - 1";
$b = "Two - 2";

echo $a . $b; // One - 1Two - 2

swap($a, $b);

echo $a . $b; // Two - 2One - 1
```

Working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ytAIR4

Comment: A note to all: this function only works properly in all cases if `$a` and `$b` are the same length, as per @m13r

Answer (score 4):

another simple method

```
$a=122;
$b=343;

extract(array('a'=>$b,'b'=>$a));

echo '$a='.$a.PHP_EOL;
echo '$b='.$b;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is another way without using a temp or a third variable.**

```
<?php
$a = "One - 1";
$b = "Two - 2";

list($b, $a) = array($a, $b);

echo $a . $b;
?>
```

**And if you want to make it a function:**

```
    <?php
    function swapValues(&$a, &$b) {
         list($b, $a) = array($a, $b);
     }
    $a = 10;
    $b = 20;
    swapValues($a, $b);

    echo $a;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $b;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help. I've made this into a PHP function swap()

```
function swap(&$var1, &$var2) {
    $tmp = $var1;
    $var1 = $var2;
    $var2 = $tmp;
}
```

Code example can be found at:

http://liljosh.com/swap-php-variables/

Answer (score 2):

3 options:

```php
$x ^= $y ^= $x ^= $y; //bitwise operators
```

or:

```php
list($x,$y) = array($y,$x);
```

or:

```php
$tmp=$x; $x=$y; $y=$tmp;
```

I think that the first option is the fastest and needs lesser memory, but it doesn’t works well with all types of variables. (example: works well only for strings with the same length)
Anyway, this method is much better than the arithmetic method, from any angle.
(Arithmetic: {$a=($a+$b)-$a; $b=($a+$b)-$b;} problem of MaxInt, and more...)

Functions for example:

```php
function swap(&$x,&$y) { $x ^= $y ^= $x ^= $y; }
function swap(&$x,&$y) { list($x,$y) = array($y,$x); }
function swap(&$x,&$y) { $tmp=$x; $x=$y; $y=$tmp; }

//usage:
swap($x,$y);
```

Comment: It works (if they have the same length).
Tested right now, on PHP5.5

Comment: code:
function swap(&$x,&$y) {$x ^= $y ^= $x ^= $y;}
$a="aaa"; $b="bbb"; swap($a,$b); echo $a,$b;

Answer (score 0):

If both variables are integers you can use mathematical approach:

```
$a = 7; $b = 10; $a = $a + $b; $b = $a - $b; $a = $a - $b;
```

Good blog post - http://booleandreams.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-swap-values-of-two-variables-without-using-a-third-variable/

Answer (score -2):

Yes I know there are lots of solutions available, but here is another one. 
You can use `parse_str()` function too. Reference [W3Schools PHP parse_str() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_parse_str.asp).

```
<?php
    $a = 10;
    $b = 'String';

    echo '$a is '.$a;
    echo '....';
    echo '$b is '.$b;

    parse_str("a=$b&b=$a");

    echo '....After Using Parse Str....';

    echo '$a is '.$a;
    echo '....';
    echo '$b is '.$b;

?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/LdhIV)

Comment: Why the hell would you do that ... and what about the case, when $b contains something like `b&a=abc`?

Answer (score -2):

I checked all solutions after that i came up with another solution that was not found anywhere. my logic is simple. i used **PHP variable ref. pattern**. means **$$**. you can read more about this by this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
$a =12;$b="ABC";
$$a =$b;
$$b= $$a.$a;
echo " a = $a and b=$b <br>now after reverse.<br>";
echo $$b;
```

//output : abc12

Comment: This code makes no sense

Comment: Although working and interesting - I didn't know about Variable Variables until reading this, although now I wish I never found out about them - the code is impractical and there's no benefit over simply using a variable called `$temp` :)

Answer (score -3):

```
$a = 'ravi';

$b = 'bhavin';

$a = $b.$a;

$b = substr($a,strlen($b),strlen($a));

$a = substr($a,0,strlen($a)-strlen($b));

echo "a=".$a.'<br/>'.'b='.$b;
```

Answer (score -4):

another answer

```
$a = $a*$b;
$b = $a/$b;
$a = $a/$b;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php

swap(50, 100);

function swap($a, $b) 
{
   $a = $a+$b;
   $b = $a - $b;
   $a = $a - $b;
   echo "A:". $a;
   echo "B:". $b;
 }
?>
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 6 **years** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Answer (score -11):

```
$a=5; $b=10; $a=($a+$b)-$a; $b=($a+$b)-$b;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, both a and b would be 10.  (10+10)-10 = 10