# A simple subtraction practice

Tags: shuffle

I want to make a little game for my son to practice subtraction ( since he won't get off the computer !! ) . i have tried this code but my problem is that i want the first number to be always higher than the second number (cause that's wht they know so far ) ..this is my code :

```
<?PHP 
$string = "1234567890";
$shuffled = str_shuffle($string);
$shuffled2 = str_shuffle($string);
$num1 = substr($shuffled, 0, 3);
$num2=substr($shuffled2, 0, 3);

if ($num2 > $num1) {
          some code here ..
} else {
echo "$num1<BR>"; 
echo "$num2<BR>"; 

$res= $num1-$num2;
echo "$res<BR>";
   }
       ?>
```

so what is the missing code here ..i was thinking (goto) back from my days of basic to  run code from the beginning until condition if satisfied ..but i don't know if that works in PHP ..
Or ...is there a way to put a condition on shuffle in the first place so it can  always return the first number higher than the second number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to simply swap `num2` and `num1` in your `if` block. Knowing that, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541730/is-there-a-php-function-for-swapping-the-values-of-two-variables) is already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the two numbers should be enough ;)