# Swap two variables value without using third variable in php

Tags: php

I want to share 1 question which is asked most of the time in interviews and I wasn't able to e answer that question, but finally I found the answer:

How to Swap 2 variable value without using 3rd variable??

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Oops sorry, i am not aware of it, i thought it was not in StackOverflow, that's why i have shared it!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got the solution.

Comment: I also had that kind of interview, they are very stupid IMO, how can they judge how good you are in your area with such trivial things?

Comment: try my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541730/is-there-a-php-function-for-swapping-the-values-of-two-variables/72650266#72650266

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This method will work for any variable type:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
print $a . ',' . $b;
```

Output:

```
6,5
```

Another simple way (which only works for numbers, not strings/arrays/etc) is

```
$a =  $a + $b;  // 5 + 6 = 11
$b = $a - $b;   // 11 - 6 = 5
$a = $a - $b;  // 11 - 5 = 6
print $a . ',' . $b;
```

Output:

```
6,5
```

Comment: $b = $a + $b - ($a = $b);

Comment: @mjolnic does variables and objects are different or same? , here is question is about variables but not objects.

Answer (score 9):

Surely you want the [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) ? At least for numeric variables.

> Conventional swapping requires the use of a temporary storage
>   variable. Using the XOR swap algorithm, however, no temporary storage
>   is needed. The algorithm is as follows:
>
> X := X XOR Y
>
> Y := X XOR Y
>
> X := X XOR Y

Although I've never seen it used in real scenarios (beyond assembler work)

Comment: it's too difficult to implement, as we want simpler approach for simple operation, like variable swapping.

Comment: Just how difficult is $a xor $b ?

Comment: not me. i upvote this :)