# Rearrange index on array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Is it possible to re-arrange indexes on arrays? Lets say String `myArray [] = {"a","b","c","d"}` and rearrange the indexes to acbd as the output, sorry for the noob question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25434679/836214 - use a temp variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary variable.

```
String temp = myarray[1];
myarray[1] = myarray[2];
myarray[2] = temp;
```

If memory is a big issue you can set it to `null` afterwards (`temp = null;`), but this usually isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

you need a temp variable

```
temp =myarray[1]
myarray[1] = myarray[2]
myarray[2] = temp
```

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder elements in Java it's best to do it with Lists. For example you can write

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
Collections.rotate(list.subList(1, 4), 1);
System.out.println("" + list);
```

and the output is [a, d, b, c, e]. Doing this kind of thing with arrays is much harder.

Comment: Thanks, this really answered my question. I didnt know about list.