# Replacing two Variables with each other's Value

Tags: php

In this code

```
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
echo $x.$y; //12
```

I want to replace `$x` and `$y` vlaues with each other, So `$x = 2` and `$y = 1`, Is that possible to be achieved without assigning **middle-variables**? Something like using a `ready-function` or like

```
$x = 1;
$y = 2;
echo $x.$y; //12
$x = &$y;
$y = &$x;
echo  $x.$y //22
```

But instead of `22` I want to get `21`.

Comment: Are the variables necessarily integers?

Comment: @TrippKinetics nope, can be strings.

Comment: `list($x, $y) = [$y, $x];`

Comment: Isn't that still using scratch space?

Comment: You can do for Integer type of variables without temp variable. For string, I think you have to use temp variable.

Comment: What @u_mulder said is correct. But it will still use swap space behind the scenes. That’s unavoidable in PHP.

Comment: duplicate of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356437/swap-two-variables-value-without-using-third-variable-in-php)