# php - how to sort all elements of array except one

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looking for elegant way to sort two of three values stored in one array. The third one can be ignored but i dont want to loose it (so unseting is not an option).

Imagine such array:

```
$r = Array("tree_type" => 1, "tree_height" = 5, "tree_age" = 2);
```

If tree_height is bigger then it's age i want to swap tree height with tree_age, so tree height is always smaller number then age.

Now I am sorting it like this:

```
if ( $r['tree_height'] > $r['tree_age'] ) {
   $tmp = $r['tree_height'];
   $r['tree_height'] = $r['tree_age'];
   $r['tree_age'] = $tmp;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but i am looking for more elegant way. The best solution would be sth like this:

```
fname($r, $r['tree_height'], $r['tree_age']);
```

fname would always swap second argument with third if it's bigger then third, otherwise would do nothing.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Kalreg.

**ANSWER:**

The shortest answer, without condition is:

```
$tmp = Array($r['tree_height'], $r['tree_age'])
sort($tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just encase the code into a function:

```
function swap(&$arr){       //NOTE SIGN & meaning passing by reference.
  if ($arr['tree_height'] > $arr['tree_age']){
    $cache_age = $arr['tree_age'] ;

    $arr['tree_age'] = $arr['tree_height'] ;
    $arr['tree_height'] = $cache_age ;
  }
}


$r = array("tree_type" => 1, "tree_height" => 5, "tree_age" => 2);
swap($r);

var_dump($r);
```

Another elegant solution: (based on [Is there a PHP function for swapping the values of two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541730/is-there-a-php-function-for-swapping-the-values-of-two-variables))

```
function swap(&$arr){       //NOTE SIGN & meaning passing by reference.
  if ($arr['tree_height'] > $arr['tree_age']){
    list($arr['tree_height'], $arr['tree_age']) = array($arr['tree_age'], $arr['tree_height']);
  }
}
```

Comment: ur answet also uses "cache_age" and works similiar as mine above so it is unfortunatelly not a solution of my problem

Comment: Just tell me, what's wrong in caching data? It is a good practice when you swap values of several variables.

Comment: And yes, it works in pretty much the same way as your solution, I just encased it into a function and passed array by reference, making it usable.

Comment: Added another solution. Check the answer.

Comment: Second solution is better although i read somewhere that using list is not a good solution because of speed of it but it is better. Tell me if i use reference then setting values to array that is referenced wouldnt change original array ?

Comment: That is the point: you desired a solution like `fname($r)`, which requires the use of passing by reference. Thus: passing by reference **will affect** the original array, otherwise you have to use `return` statement in your function.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (not tested):

```
function fname(&$a, &$b) {

    if ($a <= $b)
        return;

    $t = $a;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $t;
}

fname($r['tree_height'], $r['tree_age']);
```

EDIT: Maybe You wanted something like this?

```
function fname(&$array, $name1, $name2) {

    if ($array[$name1] <= $array[$name2])
        return;

    $t = $array[$name1];
    $array[$name1] = $array[$name2];
    $array[$name2] = $t;
}

fname($r, 'tree_height', 'tree_age');
```

Comment: Your answer is same as mine just you put it into the function.

Comment: Yes, isn't it what You asked for?

Comment: Please see the edited part of the answer. Is this what You're looking for?

Comment: I am looking for something more elegant, shorter. Remember that u make additional ($t) variable that takes memory and time.

Comment: So if You are sure that You are only using numbers, You can do additive swap or XOR swap - still three lines, but no additional variables :-) It goes like this: $a = $a ^ $b; $b = $a ^ $b; $a = $a ^ $b;