# I want to reverse array without any php function?

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried something like that but it's giving me value. I need all the elements reverse in array again.

```
 <?php
//There is an array 
  echo '<pre>';
  $arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  print_r($arr);
  $size = sizeof($arr);
 //print_r($size);

 for($i=5; $i<=$size; $i--)
 {
  echo $arr[$i];
 }

?>
```

but it gives me output "fedcba"
     I need like this `["f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]`
     reverse all of its elements without using any PHP array function and any other new variable.

Comment: What does your function return

Comment: Firstly pop out elements from array . Then again push individual elements to array in reverse format

Comment: Do you need to reverse the array, or can a new reversed array be accepted?

Comment: I need to reverse the array

Comment: You can't do that without overwriting the current values. You will need a temporary array (or string) to hold the values

Comment: Without any other variables it will be impossible. You have to use a counter or something to keep track of things.

Comment: This old post could be for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610523/reverse-array-in-javascript-without-mutating-original-array

Comment: Why you need this `without using any PHP function and any other variable` ? Even [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is a function

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding Hanky Panky's answer If you don't need any additional element then you can unset the previous values of array.

```
    <?php
    $arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

    for($i=count($arr)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
    $arr[]=$arr[$i];
    unset($arr[$i]);
    }
    print_r($arr);
   //Additionaly you can use array_values to reindex your array from 0
    print_r(array_values($arr));
    ?>
```

Fiddle is [Check here](https://3v4l.org/fugHd)

Comment: `$arr[]=$arr[$i];` in this line is `$arr` new blank array (new object)?

Comment: It is not creating new object It is assigning values to your previous array. $arr is not a new object and blank array It is a continuation of your previous array

Answer (score 0):

//Use this

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

$size = sizeof($arr);
    $res=array();
  for($i=$size-1; $i>=0; $i--){
       $res[]= $arr[$i];
  }

print_r($res);
```

Comment: thanks but I don't need any new variable or any new array to store the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the same amount of variables as your code meaning $arr, $size and $i.

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

$size = count($arr);
for($i=$size-1;$i>=0;$i--){
    $arr[$size] = $arr[$i];
    unset($arr[$i]);
    $size++;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/mEHJU

It creates:

```
array(6) {
      [6]=>
      string(1) "f"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "e"
      [8]=>
      string(1) "d"
      [9]=>
      string(1) "c"
      [10]=>
      string(1) "b"
      [11]=>
      string(1) "a"
}
```

The keys are not from 0, but that can be corrected with array_values or does it need to be corrected without that function?

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you have $i<=$size, shouldn't it be $i>=0? Secondly, you can reverse the array without any extra functions but since you are using $size variable, I hope you can use another variable $temp for swapping. Here is the sample code:

```
//original array
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
print_r($arr);
$size = sizeof($arr);

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
     $temp=$arr[$i];
     $arr[$i]=$arr[$size-1];
     $arr[$size-1]=$temp;
     $size--;

}
//reversed array
print_r ($arr);
```

Comment: Added another answer with swapping method, using neither extra function nor any new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using same variable names as yours and using swapping method, (also here you may assume $i as index from left and $size as index from right.

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
print_r($arr);
$i=0;

while ($i < sizeof($arr)/2){
    $size=$arr[$i];
    $arr[$i]=$arr[sizeof($arr)-1-$i];
    $arr[sizeof($arr)-1-$i]=$size;  
    $i=$i+1;
}

//reversed array
print_r ($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
   $arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
   print_r($arr);
   $size = sizeof($arr);
  for($i=5; $i<=$size; $i--)
  {
    if($i==$size-1)
     {
     echo '['.'"'.$arr[$i].'"',',';
     }
    if($i<$size && $i!=5 && $i>0)
     {
    echo '"'.$arr[$i].'"'.','; 
     }
    if($i==0)
     {
    echo '"'.$arr[$i].'"'.']'; 
     }
 }
  ?>//hope this helps you....
```

Answer (score -1):

ok so this is my last try

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$count = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $count/2; $i++){
  $array[$i] ^= $array[$count-$i-1] ^= $array[$i] ^= $array[$count-$i-1];
}
```

it is base on [Is there a PHP function for swapping the values of two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541730/is-there-a-php-function-for-swapping-the-values-of-two-variables)

and if you cant even use `count()` you can do simple `foreach` loop

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $one)
 $count++;
```

Comment: "without using any PHP function and any other variable"